# Local IIS host application issue in IE only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, iis

I have aspnet MVC application which hosted into local IIS.
I have one action in my controller which enumerate all files in folder but when I browse application from Mozila, chrome it works, if I browse it from IE it throw a message "Could not find a part of the path C:/mypublish/upload"

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetUploadedFileList()
    {
        try
        {
            var uploadedFile = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/FILES")).Select(s => new FileInfo(s)).OrderBy(o => o.CreationTime);
            return Json(uploadedFile.Select(s => new { s.Name, s.Length }), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { error = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Hosted on window 7 IIS 6.1
The application has windows authentication enable.

Comment: Just an observation, the slashes in your path are going the wrong way.

Comment: I resolve this issue by using Path.combine(Server.MapPath("~/FILES"),"") it works for me.